# How to install MongoDB Enterprise 4.4 on remote redhat server?

Tags: linux, mongodb, redhat, remote-server

I followed the instructions listed here, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-red-hat/, and tried to install on a remote server from my local machine. I ssh from my local machine into the server and performed the steps for installation.

I'm not sure if there are additional steps that need to be completed or whether you have to set Directory Paths that are not the default ones since you are using a server instead of local machine. My current error is when I run mongo from my terminal and I get this error

```
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
[h699972@csc2cxp00020938 ~]$ mongo --host
```

sudo vim /etc/mongod.conf and setting bindIp: 0.0.0.0 did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the mongo log file, typically at `/var/log/mongod/`. Very often the mongod service is not started or the `dbPath` folder does not exist (or miss write privileges)

Comment: I just have a mongod.log with nothing in it. It seems that it is trying to connect to connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 but I want to connect it to the remote server than I am currently on

Comment: When mongod.log is empty then the mongo service does run at all. Did you start the service?